# Mimic iframe behavior with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to embed an entire php page inside another dynamically and I cannot use an iframe to accomplish that because it would cover important parts of the applicantion and most importantly, I need to have full control over embedded page in order to insert elements with drag and drop script without having to use hacks.

I need to mimic an iframe behavior in the sense that the css from the main page and from the loaded one don't interfere with each other and I need that the scripts from the loaded page work normally.

At this time, the validation of the result isn't a concern.

Can someone help??

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
Let me be clear in one point: I can embed one page inside another using jquery. It's very simple. But, when I do that, one css interfere with the other and the js don't execute properly and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Not possible. You'd end up with malformed HTML. Two `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags etc...

Comment: This is not an issue as it's easy to solve manipulating the dom before inserting it (but it seems jquery is already solving it by itself).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me an AJAX call would do the job, as long as it's all on the same server.

If you call the page using something like:

```
    function assignRequestObject(){
    try{
    // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer
        try{
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e){
            try{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e){
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
    assignRequestObject();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = readyStateCheck;
    xmlHttp.open('GET', '/mydir/fooBar.php', true); // '/' begins at your site's root
    xmlHttp.send(null);

    readyStateCheck = function(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;      }
}
```

(this is untested)

This portion - `document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;` - would fill your div with whatever write-up your php file produces. Note that you can do this even with a .txt file.

Comment: or just use jquery ajax: `$("#mydiv").load("/mydir/fooBar.php", function(data) { this.innerHTML = data; });`

Comment: I Love JQuery! Just haven't taken the time to adopt it. :)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I just made an edition to the question to make my problem clearer.

Comment: @Jimmmy, it'll save your life!

Comment: @Robyflc check [this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/at-namespace) out. Can you implement name space on your CSS?

Comment: Also, you can do the same kind of thing with the .js you use.

Comment: @Jimmmy, this is very interesting and it would be a good solution if it worked in more browsers, but it seems most of them don't use it yet. Thanks for the idea, anyway!

Comment: well, you know, ya gotta try to think outside the box